# "On a lighter note": what is the meaning of this and how to use it?

Tags: phrases, grammaticality

If I say:

> Wow! Diwali party, that sounds great; on the lighter note, who is sponsoring it?

Am I correct in using "on the lighter note"? I am using it as saying something funny/witty.
Please let me know, if it is wrong, the correct usage of it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No. *On a lighter note* generally means *"On a less serious topic."* In addition, the phrase is typically used with the word *a*, not the word *the*.

Example:

> Many people have died during the War in Afghanistan. On a lighter note, where should we have lunch?

Comment: If i a not wrong we use it when there is no relation b/w two sentences like there is no relation between Afghanistan war and lunch ?

Comment: @Rakesh It's a phrase used to tie a conversation together, but the two sentences do not have to be related.

Comment: @Rakesh: you don't join any two sentences together. It's used when you're talking about a serious or sad topic. After the conversation is over on that topic, you want to mention something simple/trivial, like where to go to eat or to suggest to play a video game. So you say "On a lighter note... let's play some video games!" Otherwise it would sound kind of strange: "And that's why the USA nuked Japan. Hey let's get sushi!"

Comment: I think that using "on a lighter note" to connect two completely unrelated phrases such as these carries a tone of sarcasm or the unsaid statement: "We can't do much with <first statement>, so let's move on to <second statement>."

Comment: @ChrisDwyer: Hence this classic TV news segue: "Well, that's ethnic cleansing for you. On a lighter note, **are you ready for some football?!**"

Answer (score 1):

Typically used as a formal way of gracefully switching from a serious topic to a less serious one.

Answer (score 0):

Manchester United has dropped crucial points in the last two EPL encounters making the fans restless. On a lighter note, we need to drink our heads off this evening to celebrate your birthday.

Comment: I can see this is correct example, but I don't see what you are hoping this clarifies.